# Is it possible/recommended to re-use lodash lazy objects?

Tags: functional-programming, lodash

I'm wondering if it is recommended to pass around and re-use the chained lazy objects I create with lodash.

```
var filtered = _(nonFiltered).filter(...).map(...);

filtered.each(doStuff).value();

var reMapped = filtered.map(...).object(...);

//keep using reMapped and filtered, sometimes calling .value()
```

Is it safe to use lodash chained objects in this way?

Comment: In what way "safe"? And recommended for what use case?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Yes, you can absolutely do it!**

Lodash (>= v3.2) provides you with all the tools you need. It is up to you to decide when you execute a chain (by calling either `.commit()` (see below) or by calling .value() explicitly or implicitly) and you can even re-use previously created chains by injecting different collections/array/objects/values (by calling `.plant()` (see below)).

What you should consider, however, is this:

1. **Performance** ---
   The whole chain will be executed every time you execute the chain. In your example, for instance, if you execute the `reMapped` chain, the initial `filter()` and `map()` parts are executed again. Even if you've executed the `filtered` chain before. So performance-wise it might make sense at a certain point in your code to execute a chain and wrap the results with a fresh lodash wrapper. This is what `commit()` is there for.

   ```
   var filtered = _(nonFiltered).filter(...).map(...).commit();
   var reMapped = filtered.(...).commit();
   ```

   By doing so, you will execute the chain and wrap the results in a new lodash wrapper. Of course, this does not work well together with `plant()` (see below).

   [Click here for reference on `commit()`](https://lodash.com/docs#prototype-commit)
2. **Variable Lifecycle** --- Also, you need to take special care, when executing your chain, that your initial variable `nonFiltered` still points to the same object. I.e. you cannot create your chain and expect a new assignment to `nonFiltered` to automagically find its way into the chain. This is what `plant()` is there for:

   ```
   reMapped.plant(nonFiltered).value();
   ```

   Technically, when calling `plant`, the wrapper is cloned, which leaves the original wrapper unmodified. Performance-wise, the cloning is negligible.

   [Click here for reference on `plant()`](https://lodash.com/docs#prototype-plant)
3. **Memory Management** --- if you pass the wrapper around too freely you might end up with situations where the `nonFiltered` variable (more exactly the object/array it points to) normally would have been garbage collected. As long as the wrapper exists, however, the garbage collector can not clean up. This can have only a little impact on your memory footprint, but depending on the number of wrappers you create and where you store them, it can also mean that you might end up with a significantly increased memory footprint on average, depending when you will finally release the wrapper.

   The worst case situation, e.g. would be, to store wrappers on some kind of long-living objects (e.g. stored in an Angular service), wrapping the results of a heavy-weight $http response, maybe with lots of unrelevant data, that would be reduced to a fraction of the original size when executing the wrapper.

   Again, `commit` and `plant` come to the rescue. You can choose from two strategies:

   1. Either create your chain with an empty value (like this: `_().filter(...)...`) and use `plant` before executing the chain (see (2.)).
   2. Or just `commit` your chain immediately after you've defined it (see (1.))

Comment: Yeah, #1 is the one I was worried about, I specifically wanted to avoid re-running the first lazy steps (`filter` and `map`) over and over again. Is this behavior documented anywhere?

Comment: Unfortunately not. But a quick test shows it (just add a console.log inside your filter function) ... but I've found a workaround for this (will update my post in a minute)

Comment: Wonderful answer, more than I expected, `commit` is a great tip. Thanks!